# PHP Header redirect not working anymore when i use event.preventDefault() on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my PHP code was working fine until I decided to use jquery for my signup page to handle and check the fields, it's working there is no error, everything is submitted to the server correctly so there is no problem with the code PHP nor jquery, but the  header("location: ../****.php") no longer send me to another page after I hit submit, instead it loads the new page on top of the old one without refreshing.
This is my jquery code for the signup page:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
      var username = $("#signup-username").val();
      var pwd = $("#signup-pwd").val();
   $(".form-message").load("includes/user-signup.inc.php",{
      username: username,
      pwd: pwd
     });
     });
     });
</script>
```

and this is my PHP code in my include page:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';
$username= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);
$errorEmpty = $errorValid = false;
if(empty($username)|| empty($pwd)){
    echo "Fill in all Fields!";
    $errorEmpty = true;
}
else{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
        $uid = $username;
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $usernamecheck = mysqli_num_rows($result); // check if the results
        $rowNum = $result->num_rows;
        if($rowNum > 0){
            echo "Username is taken!";
            $errorValid = true;
}
else{
    $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$uid, $password);
    $uid = $username;
    $password = $hashedPwd;
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    header("location: ../user-login.php");
}
}
}else{
header("location: ../user-signup.php");
exit();
}
?>
<script> 
$("#signup-username, #signup-pwd").removeClass("input-error");
    var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty; ?>";
    var errorValid = "<?php echo $errorValid; ?>";
if (errorEmpty == true $$ errorValid == true){
    $("#signup-username, #signup-pwd").addClass("input-error");
if (errorFEmpty == false && errorValid == false){
$("#signup-username, #signup-pwd,").val("");
    }
</script>
```

how do I fix this?

Comment: Full code please, for security sake you can change variable names. You're code almost not correct with the asterisk in it.

Comment: @PreciousTom here you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".form-message").load("includes/user-signup.inc.php",{
  username: username,
  pwd: pwd
});
```

When the above code gets to the point where header("Location: file.php");
It'll fetch that file into `$(".form-message")`
To Avoid this you can use ajax to post data and javascript inbuilt redirection

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "includes/user-signup.inc.php",
  data: "username="+ username +"&pwd="+ pwd,
  success: function(data) {
    window.location.href = "../****.php";
  }
});
```

Hope this answer was helpful.

Comment: data: "username="+ username +"&pwd="+ pwd,
is this written correctly?

Comment: Yes it is. @NizarWakour

Comment: it doesn't work for me, I don't get this part 
 data: "username="+ username +"&pwd="+ pwd,
why is it "username=" and "&pwd=" ? and i have more variables whats the pattern so i can add them because i don't get this pattern here.
and  success: function(data) {
    window.location.href = "../****.php";
means if the data is successful go to the page I want ?if so, successful in what way? I don't want the page to refresh until the data is successfully added to the database.
if there is a different better way to validate my form using Java I'd like to use that then.

Comment: sorry I'm still new to javascript, I already use "required pattern" with HTML and check with PHP which is more secure but PHP needs to refresh and I want to check if username and email are already in the database without refreshing the page. thank you

Comment: here is a tip
includes/user-signup.inc.php?username=username&pwd=pwd
Same thing as
username="+ username +"&pwd="+ pwd
Where the + means concatenate.
You could choose to return a piece of text from the php script's end.
and use if (data == "that text returned"){
window.location.href = "../****.php"; } else {
$(".form-report").text("Oops! login failed");
}

Comment: Would you prefer i write you a new login script(Php) and ajax(javascript)
That works, safe and secure.

Comment: yes, thank you! that would be awesome if it's not too much trouble, a sign-up system only with username and password where it checks if username already exist, I can work the rest once I see how it work.

Answer (score 0):

Your code operates exactly as it should.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#myForm").submit(function(event){
         // THIS LINE RIGHT HERE
         event.preventDefault();
      ******************
        $(".form-message").load("includes/user-signup.inc.php",{
      ******************
        });
     });
  });
```

Event prevent default stops the redirect action. Additionally you then use jquery to load the contents of the file into the DOM element with the class:

```
.form-message
```

Remove event.preventDefault();

Comment: @PreciousAniefiok this isn't my code. I just copied it from OP

Comment: @PreciousAniefiok I'm not the OP, I posted an answer. Go up some more and ask him

Comment: I get it but can I fix it somehow without removing event.preventDefault();?